# Delay changing pages

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a function that happens lots of times on the server and when I have counted the correct number of successes, it moves me to my Complete page. Huzzah!

But I want to pause, and javascript hates pausing. I want my users to savor that 100%.

```
setTimeout(app.showPage(app.pages.Complete),1000);
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Although the provided answer is correct, that you need to include `function(){}`, it seems that you have another dependency on a process finishing successfully on the server x amount of times. If that is the case I would not necessarily recommend setTimeout function as this does not actually account for that. Rather I would include a counter variable and increase that in your server withSuccessHandler function. If you include more detail I have a possible solution for you.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the timeout to start until after the other processes have completed (which is indeed figured out by counting the length of the output).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

  app.showPage(app.pages.Complete);

}, 1000);
```